# Count all duplicates of each value

Tags: sql, sql-server

I would like a SQL query for MS Jet 4.0 (MSSql?) to get a count of all the duplicates of each number in a database.

The fields are: `id` (autonum), `number` (text)

I have a database with a lot of numbers.

Each number should be returned in numerical order, without duplicates, with a count of all duplicates.

Number-fields containing 1, 2, 2, 3, 1, 4, 2 should return:

```
1, 2  
2, 3  
3, 1  
4, 1
```

Answer (score 44, accepted):

```
SELECT   col,
         COUNT(dupe_col) AS dupe_cnt
FROM     TABLE
GROUP BY col
HAVING   COUNT(dupe_col) > 1
ORDER BY COUNT(dupe_col) DESC
```

Comment: Don't think you need the `HAVING` as OP included the column values of 3 and 4, both with a count of 1, in his expected results.

Comment: Also, the OP has the order by col, not by the count, unless 2 is higher than 3 now =)

Comment: -1, A: `count(named_column)` is slower than `count(*)` B: `Having...` is incorrect given the question. C: `order by` clause should be `order by col` D: `table` is a reserved word

Comment: best answer with johans changes

Answer (score 24):

```
SELECT number, COUNT(*)
    FROM YourTable
    GROUP BY number
    ORDER BY number
```

Comment: lol, I'd be wrong though, I was sorting times wrong in my head.

Comment: @mootinator: No, earliest answer was @Duncan's, then @dpmattingly's. Which one you count as ealiest corerct, is up to you.

Comment: Actually @Duncan's is incorrect because it doesn't explicitly specify order.  I tend to put a high value on understanding the question the OP is asking when picking a correct answer.

Answer (score 6):

This is quite simple.

Assuming the data is stored in a column called A in a table called T, you can use

```
select A, count(A) from T group by A
```

Answer (score 5):

You'd want the `COUNT` operator.

```
SELECT NUMBER, COUNT(*) 
FROM T_NAME
GROUP BY NUMBER
ORDER BY NUMBER ASC
```

Answer (score 0):

If you want to check repetition more than 1 in descending order 
then implement below query.

```
SELECT   duplicate_data,COUNT(duplicate_data) AS duplicate_data
FROM     duplicate_data_table_name 
GROUP BY duplicate_data
HAVING   COUNT(duplicate_data) > 1
ORDER BY COUNT(duplicate_data) DESC
```

If want simple count query.

```
SELECT   COUNT(duplicate_data) AS duplicate_data
FROM     duplicate_data_table_name 
GROUP BY duplicate_data
ORDER BY COUNT(duplicate_data) DESC
```